# need help in making animation smooth

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I am trying to make a smooth animation here is what I did

[Demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/94S8a/)

Please see while transforming there is a glitch, it's not smooth.
Anyone can please help making it smooth animation.
I can't change the div structure, please try to answer with this div structure.

**HTML**

```
<div id="tilecontainer">
    <div class="tile">
        <div class="tileinnerdiv">
            <span class="tileheader">Risk Analysis</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#tilecontainer
{
    width: 900px;
    height: 650px;
    background: REd;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px;
    -moz-perspective: 850px;
    -ms-perspective: 850px;
    -webkit-perspective: 850px;
    perspective: 850px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.tile
{
    width: 185px;
    height: 180px;
    background: grey;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    position:ablosute;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 50px 0px blue;

    animation: myani 0.5s 1 ease;
}

.tileinnerdiv
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.tileheader
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.tile:hover
{
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(45, 90, 0, 10deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate3d(45, 90, 0, 10deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(45, 90, 0, 10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(45, 90, 0, 10deg);
    transform: rotate3d(45, 90, 0, 10deg);
}

@keyframes myani
{
    from{transform: rotateY(60deg);}
    to{transform: rotateY(0deg);}
}
```

Comment: close voted, as you tricked the system by highlighting your jsfiddle link and you ignored the warning

Comment: @Mr.Alien He's a completely new user to SO. Have to patience and edit the posts in these cases. You can call close votes without comments, too. Enough offtopic here.

Comment: @Smamatti New user or not, the hint *"Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code."* is quite clear.

Comment: @Smamatti If you keep editing the posts, users will never learn, and hence, we [show them a warning](http://i.imgur.com/M9wb4Yx.png) which is also shown to new users

Comment: I tried what shown in suggestion to add link, but not able to. kind request, Please make link inserting little user friendly.

Comment: What is close vote? How does this affect a question? please explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use transition, see http://jsfiddle.net/94S8a/1/

```
transition: 1s;
```